# Calculate area from Lat/Lon matrix or within a 50% contour for multiple polygons in R

Tags: r, coordinates, geospatial, area, contour

I want to find the total area from multiple polygons within different contour lines from kernel densities (kde2d).
Here is an image of the kernel density and the 50% contour line. How do I calculate the area within the 50% contour line?

I also created a matrix of lat lon coordinates, which represents the points within this 50% contour line. Would it be easier to calculate the total area using these points.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you doing kde on lat-long coordinates? Because that's probably wrong. 1 degree of lat is not 1 degree of long, and so your circular kernel isn't really circular. Convert to a cartesian coordinate system (a UTM zone probably) and try again. Then you'll end up with metres as coordinates and area calculations are easy.

Comment: Just to emphasise the coordinate system thing, at your latitude, just off the Antarctic peninsula, the circumference of the 64-degree lat line is 0.43 times the equatorial circumference, so a degree of longitude is 2.28 times bigger than a degree of latitude. So your kernel density is being estimated by a 2.28:1 eccentricity ellipse. Convert to something like epsg:32720 and try again! http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32720/ (see spTransform in sp and rgdal packages)

Comment: @Spacedman, Thanks for catching that! It turns out the kernels are nearly identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have your coordinates in a cartesian system, and have done the kernel smoothing using those coordinates, you can use the `contourLines` function to get the coordinates of the lines, and then the `areapl` function from the `splancs` package to compute the area of each simple ring.

For example, using the example in `help(kde2d)`:

```
attach(geyser)

plot(duration, waiting, xlim = c(0.5,6), ylim = c(40,100))
f1 <- kde2d(duration, waiting, n = 50, lims = c(0.5, 6, 40, 100))
image(f1)
contour(f1)
```

so that's our data set up - suppose we want the area in the 0.008 contour:

```
C8 = contourLines(f1,level=0.008)
length(C8)
[1] 3
```

Now `C8` is a list of length 3. We need to apply the `areapl` function over each of these:

```
> sapply(C8,function(ring){areapl(cbind(ring$x,ring$y))})
[1] 14.65282 12.27329 14.75005
```

And we can obviously sum:

```
> sum(sapply(C8,function(ring){areapl(cbind(ring$x,ring$y))}))
[1] 41.67617
```

Now this only makes sense if the coordinates are cartesian, and if the contour lines are complete loops. If the 0.008 contour was near the edge then its possible for the contour to get clipped to the bounding box and then bad things happen. Check at least that the last point of each ring is the same as the first.